# how to track move to the next child group record in linq c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
Department  Gender  Name
----------  ------  ----
HR          M       Mike
HR          F       Johnna
HR          M       Erick
HR          M       Yvon
HR          F       Rachel
IT          F       Olga
IT          M       Saya
IT          F       Aldis

I am trying to group Employee by Department and Gender and assign 
an incremental number to each name base of the department and the gender 


Name   Assign 
Mike   1     -> M in HR
Erick  1     -> M in HR
Yvon   1     -> M in HR
Johnna 2     -> F in HR
Rachel 2     -> F in HR

Saya   1     -> M in IT
Olga   2     -> F in IT
Aldis  2     -> F in IT
```

The issue is that when grouping base of two fields it became difficult to 
track the change and know when the child group change inside the parent grouping 
in our case department and gender

The number is increment base on the gender not the departmentName

Comment: It's unclear what the numbers are relating to.  From your example it looks like all `M` have `1` and `F` have `2`.  Also is this in a database or a collection in memory?  Which ORM are you using if it's a database?

Comment: The behavior is that all record should be grouped by Department and then by Gender. All element in the first group of department HR which is M while be assigned , and the sencond group in department HR will be assigned 2, the third group will be assign 3 and so on. the next department will be the same. So how to assign those caculated number during execution of the foreach loop. i am using a collection in memory with linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like males are always assigned `1`, and females `2`, in which case you could write:

```
foreach (var employee in employees) {
  employee.AssignedNumber = (employee.Gender == 'M') ? 1 : 2;
}
```

However, if this is not always true (for example, if your table accepts additional gender types, or if some departments do not have any males), then you could write:

```
var departments = employees.GroupBy(o => o.Department);
foreach (var department in departments) {
  var genders = department.GroupBy(o => o.Gender);
  var num = 1;
  foreach (var gender in genders) {
    foreach (var employee in gender) {
      employee.AssignedNumber = num;
    }
    num++;
  }
}
```